# How To Calculate Time of Collision With Simultaneous Movements

Tags: problem-solving, classical-mechanics

At time $t0 = 0$, a particle $P1$ of mass $m$ is projected vertically from the ground
with speed $v0 > 0$. This particle reaches its maximum height $h1$ at time $t = t1$.
At time $t2 > t1$, when this particle has the speed $v0/3$, another particle $P2$ of mass
$3m$ is projected vertically upwards from the same point of the ground with speed $V0$.
Assume that the gravitational acceleration $g$ is constant.
(i) Determine $t1$ and $h1$. 
(ii) Determine $t2$ and the height $h2$ of $P1$ at $t$ = $t2$. 
(iii) Determine the time $t3$ and height $h3$ of the collision between particles $P1$ and $P2$

So the question (iii) I am struggling with.

I have calculated the following:
$t1 = \frac{V0}{g}$

$h1 = \frac{V0^2}{2g}$

$t2 = \frac{4V0}{3g}$
$h2 = \frac{4V0^2}{9g}$   where $g$ is the constant gravity.

I have used the SUVAT formulae to try to work out the time of collision by assuming the displacement is the same for both particles, and putting $uv+0.5at^2$ of particle $1 = uv+0.5at^2$ of particle 2. However Im not sure i'm correct in doing this.

Any advice is appreciated (and sorry if this is long-winded, first time poster)

Comment: Write the motion equation of both particles (height as a function of time) and equate the heights. Hint: $ -gt^2/2+v_0t=-g(t-t_2)^2/2+v_0(t-t_2)$.

Comment: Please write down the question here rather than posting a link, it doesn't take much.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Would one of the accelerations not be positive though because theyre moveing in opposite directions?

Comment: @Couchy311 Sorry about that, have edited it in

Comment: @Matt: certainly not. Gravity cannot be upward for one of the particles.

Comment: @YvesDaoust apologies i meant to say velocity. Also, could you please explain the t-t2 part to me as i have an idea of what you mean but am not sure if i am indeed thinking the same

Comment: @Matt: yes, we are.